# Not able to click the Matched Row button in the repeater in protractor Test Case?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

This is my test code when I run my test it always click the last row button, not able to click the matched row button.

```
it('repeater element check',function(){
 browser.get('http://test.worker.mondaz.com/#/Company/Select');
 browser.sleep(1000);
 var result = element.all(by.repeater('co in CoList'));
 result.then(function(arr) {    
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
   arr[i].element(by.binding('co.Nm')).getText().then(function(text) {
    if(text=="Monday Ventures Private Limited") { 
     console.log(text);
     console.log("Mathced");
     console.log(i);//this is always giving my total row count  
     element(by.repeater('coCoList').row(i)).element(by.name('customRadio')).click();
    } 
   });  
  } 
 });   
}
```

I am a beginner for Angular Protractor test case.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for-loop over your array of promises returned by `element.all`, you should use [element.all(locator).filter(filterFn)](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter out the "Monday" element.

If I understand your present code correctly, it will first loop through the array of promises without waiting for their completion. Because of this `i` will be equal to the total number of rows. Only then the actually matched row's `function (text) { ... }` is executed, but with the value of `i` you did not expect.

EDIT: Including the working code based on this answer, taken from @chandru-yadhav's comment:

```
var items = element.all(by.repeater('co in CoList')).filter(function(item) { 
  return item.element(by.binding('co.Nm')).getText().then(function(label) { 
    return label === 'Monday Ventures Private Limited'; 
  }); 
}); 
items.get(0).element(by.name('customRadio')).click();
```

Comment: var items = element.all(by.repeater('co in CoList')).filter(function(item) {
            return        item.element(by.binding('co.Nm')).getText().then(function(label) {
            return label === 'Monday Ventures Private Limited';
                });
              });
            items.get(0).element(by.name('customRadio')).click();

Comment: Thanks avandeursen...i got the solution.

Comment: Glad it worked. I updated the answer with your code.

Comment: Since this seems to be your first StackOverflow question: The next thing to do as a good citizen is to inform others that this is the correct answer by accepting it.

Comment: Hi avandeursen..today i have another problem it may be silly to ask but i sorry for that.See                                                                                                               var items = element.all(by.repeater('co in CoList')).filter(function(item) {              return item.element(by.binding('co.Nm')).getText().then(function(label) {  var CoNm=logic to get the company name from DB.                                            return label === CoNm; instead of hardcoding the company name to match in the repeater if i try something like this its not woking.

Comment: Hi avandeursen..Got the solution actually time is the problem i had given browser.sleep(10000) then its finding the element and clicking.Thanks

Comment: @chandruYadhav: would you consider accepting the answer here, as has already been suggested?